# Consuming an RPC/encoded WSDL with java

Tags: java, web-services, intellij-idea, wsdl, jax-rpc

I have successfully consumed this same wsdl with php using NuSOAP. This is the method the company has set up to use, but I was told I am welcome to try any other way.  I would like to move the consumption to my middleware and this would be using java.  I've done enough scavenging to find that I need to use JAX-RPC somehow, but all I can find is how-tos using some IDE. And on top of that the method doesn't work, or basic steps that a noob like me needs are left out.  Most of the posts are ancient too.

I am using IntelliJ.  If you know step by step how to consume an rpc/encoded wsdl(has authentication) in IntelliJ from IDE download to successful client generation, then please help me.

OR

If you know where the information on how to accomplish this manually(i.e. without IDE) that would be just as appreciated.  But please check the validity of it, I've already wasted time I don't have on this, thanks!

Comment: And what is your **concrete** question?

Comment: Either assume I have just downloaded the intellij IDE and I need to Generate Java Code from an RPC/encoded wsdl

Comment: or link me to something that shows how to consume an rpc/encoded wsdl in java without the help of an IDE(I say just link this one bc I imagine this is 100x more steps than using an IDE)

Comment: [JAX-RPC Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXRPC.html). [Apache Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis/) (not Axis2, just Axis) also supports RPC/Encoded.